# Java Constructors: Error "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

I have been desperately trying to make this piece of code work. This is my first time working with objects/constructors (I'm a new programmer) and it is confusing me. I'll be totally honest; I don't know what the issue is. I have tried many things so this code is quite messy. I also got fed up and started again making a second code which also doesn't work for the same reason as the first, though that code is structured slightly different. I will post both attempts bellow in the hopes that someone can see my error. Thankyou!

**Attempt 1:**

```
class Circle
{
    private static double r;
    public static double rd;
    public double Circle( double r, double rd )
 {
        r = rd;
        return r;
 }
    public double calCircumference(double r)
 {
        return 2*Math.PI*r;
}
    public static double calArea(double r)
{
        return Math.PI*r*r;
}

}
class CircleApp
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
        double rd = Double.parseDouble( args[0] );
        System.out.println( "Circle radius = " + rd );

        // create an object of Circle with the radius rd
        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        double cir = circle1.calCircumference();
        double area = circle1.calArea();
        System.out.println("Circumference = " + cir);
        System.out.println("Area = " + area);
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
class Circle
{   
    public double rd = Double.parseDouble( args[0] );   
    private double r;

    public void Circle( double rd )
 {
    double r = rd;
 }
    private double calCircumference(double r)
 {
        return 2*Math.PI*r;
}
    public double calArea()
{
        return Math.PI*r*r;
}
}
class CircleApp2
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
        System.out.println( "Circle radius = " + rd );
        // create an object of Circle with the radius rd
        Circle circle1 = new Circle( rd);
        double cir = circle1.calCircumference();
        double area = circle1.calArea();
        System.out.println("Circumference = " + cir);
        System.out.println("Area = " + area);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, because I assume my coding will likely make most of you want to rip my head off, please do criticise any part of it. I am just starting the learning process here so any feedback/critiques would be very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: `calCircumference(double r)` expects a `double` to be given. Which is weird, because the `Circle` instance already has a radius field. Why don't you use this?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not `void` methods. This

```
public void Circle( double rd )
```

should be

```
public Circle( double rd ){
    this.r = rd;
}
```

Then next issue is

```
private double calCircumference(double r)
```

should be

```
private double calCircumference()
```

and

```
public double rd = Double.parseDouble( args[0] );
```

does not make sense, that isn't in `main`. Putting everything together,

```
class Circle {
    private double r;

    public Circle(double rd) {
        this.r = rd;
    }

    public double calCircumference() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * r;
    }

    public double calArea() {
        return Math.PI * r * r;
    }
}
```

And then

```
class CircleApp2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double rd = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Circle radius = " + rd);
        // create an object of Circle with the radius rd
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(rd);
        double cir = circle1.calCircumference();
        double area = circle1.calArea();
        System.out.println("Circumference = " + cir);
        System.out.println("Area = " + area);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems here.

Firstly, in both versions, you're declaring *methods* rather than constructors. This is a method declaration:

```java
public double Circle( double r, double rd )
```

This is a constructor declaration:

```java
public Circle( double r, double rd )
```

A constructor doesn't specify a return type.

Next, in your first attempt, you have a comment saying you're creating a circle with radius `rd`, but you're not actually passing in `rd`:

```java
// create an object of Circle with the radius rd
Circle circle1 = new Circle();
```

That should be

```java
Circle circle1 = new Circle(rd);
```

... but in attempt 1 you've *also* got two parameters in method-that-should-be-a-constructor, where you only want 1.

In attempt 2, you're trying to use the `rd` variable in `CircleApp2`, but it's only *declared* in `Circle`... and that declaration won't work because it's trying to use `args`, which only exists in `main`.

One problem is that you've written too much code before trying to build. There's no point in writing methods to calculate the circumference and area while you can't create an instance. Start from minimal code, get *that* compiling, and then you can add to it. Here's my suggestion for a starting point:

```java
// I generally go along with the idea of "design for inheritance or prohibit it",
// hence the class being declared as final, but you probably don't need to worry about
// that too much when you're starting out.
public final class Circle
{
    // I'd recommend making fields final where possible, and giving them
    // more meaningful names than "r" or "rd". (It's not *too* bad in the
    // context of a circle, but "radius" is still better.
    private final double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}

public final class CircleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        Circle circle = new Circle(radius);
    }
}
```

Now there's much less code to look at - so if you don't understand something, it'll be easier to pinpoint what it is.